# Audible Caller ID on Galaxy S3

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Every time I recieve a call or a text message my phone audibly says out the name of the caller/sender.

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a configuration that must be active to give you that information, usually it is used when you're driving, to prevent accidents:

## **Turn off the voice notifications:**

1. Go to settings menu
2. Click on "Voice input and output" option
3. Select the option "Text-to-speech settings".
4. Uncheck the Driving mode setting.

[image: Menu options print screen]

**From the [user's manual](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-I9300MBAVOD-downloads?isManualDownload=true#)**
Driving mode: Activate Driving mode to provide audible notifications for incoming calls, messages, or event details.

---

## **Change alerts on call settings:**

1. Settings
2. Call Settings
3. All calls
4. Alerts on call
5. Change from "voice" to "vibration" or "off" etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the option within Settings as mentioned above on my S3. Instead I drag down the top toolbar and uncheck the Driving Mode option. (Scroll to the right as it is not usually immediately visible.)

Comment: Great - thanks - didn't know I could scroll top toolbar down so somerthing else I've learned !